# Discount Price is not being added into my Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#

In my code, I am supposed to add a 10% discount if the user clicks on the Pay in Advanced button (btnAdvanced) in my form. So let's say the user chooses 3 adults, 0 children, and 1 day pass with no parking pass. The total should add up $132.20, but it is getting stuck on $147.
Below is my code.

```
private void btnAdvance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double dblAdultPrice = 0; //adult price
            double dblChildPrice = 0; //child price
            double dblDiscountPercent = .10;
            

            if (lstAdult.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                //User Selected no Adult
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose an Adult value");
            }
            else
            {
                dblAdultPrice = 49 * lstAdult.SelectedIndex; // this could require a data type conversion               
            }

            // get child prices
            if (lstChildren.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                //User Selected no Adult
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose a Child value");
            }
            else
            {
                dblChildPrice = 42 * lstChildren.SelectedIndex;
            }

            // calculate day
            double dblSecondaryPrice = 0;
            double dblSecondDayPrice = 0;

            if (rdoTwo.Checked)
            {
                dblSecondDayPrice = 25.00;
            }

            //parking pass
            double dblParkingPrice = 0;

            if (ChkParking.Checked)
            {
                dblParkingPrice = 15.00;
            }

            //calculate
            double dblGrandTotal = dblAdultPrice + dblSecondaryPrice + dblChildPrice + dblSecondDayPrice + dblParkingPrice *10;
            
            lblTotal.Text = dblGrandTotal.ToString("N2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great time to use a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the results of each operation and the changing values of your variables.  When you do this, which specific operation in your code first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do anything with `btnAdvanced`

Comment: Note: never use the `double` type for monetary values! Use `decimal` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
  private void btnAdvance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double dblAdultPrice = 0; //adult price
            double dblChildPrice = 0; //child price
            
            

            if (lstAdult.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                //User Selected no Adult
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose an Adult value");
            }
            else
            {
                dblAdultPrice = 49 * lstAdult.SelectedIndex; // this could require a data type conversion               
            }

            // get child prices
            if (lstChildren.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                //User Selected no Adult
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose a Child value");
            }
            else
            {
                dblChildPrice = 42 * lstChildren.SelectedIndex;
            }

            // calculate day
            double dblSecondaryPrice = 0;
            double dblSecondDayPrice = 0;

            if (rdoTwo.Checked)
            {
                dblSecondDayPrice = 25.00;
            }

            //parking pass
            double dblParkingPrice = 0;

            if (ChkParking.Checked)
            {
                dblParkingPrice = 15.00;
            }

            //calculate
            double dblGrandTotal = dblAdultPrice + dblSecondaryPrice + dblChildPrice + dblSecondDayPrice + dblParkingPrice;
            double dblDiscountPercent = dblGrandTotal * .10;
            double dblGrandTotalDiscount = dblGrandTotal - dblDiscountPercent;

            lblTotal.Text = dblGrandTotalDiscount.ToString("N2");
        }
    }
}
```

Figured it out, I added more DBLs at the end which is

```
double dblGrandTotal = dblAdultPrice + dblSecondaryPrice + dblChildPrice + dblSecondDayPrice + dblParkingPrice;
            double dblDiscountPercent = dblGrandTotal * .10;
            double dblGrandTotalDiscount = dblGrandTotal - dblDiscountPercent;

            lblTotal.Text = dblGrandTotalDiscount.ToString("N2");
```